# Mongo db ubuntu 16.04 cant start service

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu

I reinstalled mongo following this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04 but it seems it wont start, this is the result of sudo systemctl status mongodb

```
 ● mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-04-05 16:31:03 UTC; 6s ago
  Process: 14024 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Main PID: 14024 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)    

Apr 05 16:31:02 nodejs-512mb-fra1-01 systemd[1]: Started  High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Apr 05 16:31:03 nodejs-512mb-fra1-01 mongod[14024]: error command line: unrecognized line in 'storage:'
Apr 05 16:31:03 nodejs-512mb-fra1-01 mongod[14024]: use --help for help
Apr 05 16:31:03 nodejs-512mb-fra1-01 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 05 16:31:03 nodejs-512mb-fra1-01 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 05 16:31:03 nodejs-512mb-fra1-01 systemd[1]: mongodb.service:     Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

my mongod.conf looks like this

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
  net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


#processManagement:

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

If i try to comment out the storage lin it goes the same oerror on the systemLog line

Comment: Can you post your ``/etc/mongod.conf`` file please?

Comment: i added the mongod.conf file

Comment: The ``net`` line as you have shown is not correct, it should be un-indented.

Comment: @Pjtor were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: no, i switched to mysql

Comment: the net line didnt solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The error message says *unrecognized line in 'storage:'*, check your `/etc/mongod.conf` file for tabs or any strange/special characters at near the storage setting.

You can also validate that your config file is valid YAML here:

http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/